# Why is the executable placed in the obj\Debug or obj\Release folder in Visual Basic of VS2005?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to update an application that was developed a couple of months ago on VB of Visual Studio 2005.

The "**Build output path:**" for the project is pointing to a folder in which I collected a few executables related to my activity, **BinDir/**. It is just next to the project's folder **ProjName/** on my disk.

Contrary to the past, when I build my project now, the **.exe** is created in the **ProjName/obj/Debug** folder, instead of being directed to the **BinDir/Debug** folder.

In the IDE's **Output** tab (while building), the path of the generated executable appears correctly, but in reality it is located somewhere else.

Why is it so?

UPDATE: Something very peculiar is going on my computer today... A couple of hours later I tried again and now it seems like the executable is created in both places. The obj/ version is just redundant now.

Comment: Please don't cross post - if you get the wrong site (not forum) the question will be migrated for you.

Comment: @ChrisF - searching the two sites, this topic seems to appear in both. At first, I thought SU is the appropriate for the question. Only after posting, I searched SO and found that it is a valid topic here as well. The other site is less responsive so I tried my luck here. I'd migrate it myself if I had the permissions.

Comment: It's a topic that can appear on both, but as it's about a programming tool it *is* on topic for Stack Overflow. You can always flag posts for moderator attention and they'll migrate it for you (if the community doesn't get there first).

Comment: @ChrisF - OK, went to delete the other post, but I see it was done already. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe seeing in the Update is what usually happens with Visual Basic builds in Visual Studio 2005.  The build creates the executable in an intermediate directory (obj\debug) and then copies the executable from there to the final build output directory (bindir\debug)

With the usual minimal logging turned on, if you examine the build output, you should see the vbc command include the switch `/out:obj\Debug\yourproject.exe` which tells the compiler to create the executable in the obj\debug fdirectory.  Then you should see the file get moved to the build output `yourproject -> C:\TestPrograms\Vb.net\yourproject\bin\Debug\yourproject.exe`

If you use Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Build and Run to set the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" property to "Detailed" you can see a lot more activity against the obj\debug directory and then see the various project output files being copied from that intermediate directory to the build output directory.

The macros `$(Targetdir)` and `$(IntermediateOutputPath)` can be used to access these two directories as can be seen using  a build event like this...

```
echo target: $(Targetdir)
echo intermediate: $(IntermediateOutputPath)
```

In the original question, it sounds like the copy from intermediate to build output either failed or was not attempted leaving you with only one copy of the exe in the intermediate directory.

It's too late to go back and look now but typically the build output window will tell you more about why the copy failed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Frank. When you say "*it's what usually happens with Visual Basic builds in Visual Studio 2005*", do you mean that it is usual for the exe not to be placed in the target folder? As I mentioned in the question, the Output tab did show the required place but the file was not really there (the vshost file was, though).

Comment: Sorry I focused on the "Update" part of your question and didn't address the original question properly.  What you should expect to see is the exe first be created in the intermediate folder (ProjName/obj/Debug) and then be copied to the Build Output Path (BinDir/Debug).  In the first half of your question it sounds like the copy failed (or was not attempted) for some reason.  The build output window might tell you more but you probably don't have that available anymore.

Comment: thanks a lot for $(IntermediateOutputPath) i have another problem so i solved it using $(IntermediateOutputPath).